# Calling a non-static function of a UIViewController class

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller

I am trying to build a mobile cross-platform ios application with c#, and I got stuck at this point, because I cannot call a non static function of my UIViewController.
Here is my Main.cs:

```
...
namespace BSoft.iOS
{
public class Application 
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UIApplication.Main(args, null, "AppDelegate");
    }

    public static void OpenWebPage(string link, UIViewController controller)
    {
        UIStoryboard board = UIStoryboard.FromName("Main", null);
        UIViewController ctrl = (UIViewController)board.InstantiateViewController("WebViewController");
        /// here I should call SetLink() from WebViewController class
        ctrl.ModalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyle.PartialCurl;
        controller.PresentViewController(ctrl, true, null);
    }

}
}
```

And here is the WebViewController class:

```
...
namespace BSoft.iOS
{
public partial class WebViewController : UIViewController
{
    WKWebView WebViewer;

    public WebViewController(IntPtr handle) : base(handle)
    {
    }

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        WebViewer = new WKWebView(View.Frame, new WebKit.WKWebViewConfiguration());
        WebViewer.SizeToFit();
        WebViewer.LoadRequest(Foundation.NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(Foundation.NSUrl.FromString("https://www.360bsoft.com/register")));
        WebViewerContainer.AddSubview(WebViewer);
    }

    public void SetLink(string link)
    {
        if(WebViewer!=null)
            WebViewer.LoadRequest(Foundation.NSUrlRequest.FromUrl(Foundation.NSUrl.FromString(link)));
    }

    public override void DidReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        base.DidReceiveMemoryWarning();
    }
}
}
```

In my storyboard, I have attributed to my webview ViewController a custom class ( WebViewController ) and a Identity ( WebViewController ), the problem is that I cannot call SetLink from my main app, when I change the view.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In main.cs, try casting ctrl to WebViewController instead of UIViewController:

```
WebViewController ctrl = (WebViewController)board.InstantiateViewController("WebViewController");
```

Glad it works. The reason why this *wasn't* working is that 'SetLink' is not defined on the UIViewController class, which is the type you were previously casting 'ctrl' to. side note: It actually would be possible to call it dynamically in that case, but that'd be an unnecessary complication for your situation.